# how to upgrade subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using Python 3.4.4 and noticed that my subprocess module does not support run()  and I still have to use call().I thought of upgrading subprocess but no success.

```
 C:\Users\thakurak>pip install subprocess
Collecting subprocess
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement subprocess (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for subprocess
```

How can I upgrade my subprocess module?

Comment: `subprocess` is a built-in module.

Comment: so does that means, if I need an updated version , I have to use python 3.6

Comment: Yes, the Python package contains it. Look for the version you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try it as below script

```
pip install --upgrade  subprocess.run
```